# Is there a visual web editor based on bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap is a great framework, and I want to know if there a tool that could give you the possibility of dragging HTML component resizing them, moving them, changing the colours... and in the same time HTML code is getting generated, where the CSS is based on bootstrap wouldn't that be great?

EDIT: I found this one recently http://pingendo.com/

Comment: Consider http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I know of 3 Bootstrap "editors", 2 of which have drag-and-drop feature. I don't think you'll find *all* of the features your talking about (at least not yet) in any one of them.

Take a look at..

[**DivShot**](http://www.divshot.com/) -- (try/buy) Drag/drop, HTML/CSS editing, supports Bootstrap, Foundation and Ratchet

<strike>[**JetStrap**](http://jetstrap.com/) -- (try/buy) Bootstrap only, Drag/drop, HTML/CSS/JS editing</strike>

[**Bootply**](http://bootply.com/) -- (free) Bootstrap HTML/CSS/JS editing, drag+drop, sharing/collaboration, Bootstrap snippets

[**LayoutIt**](http://www.layoutit.com/) -- (donation) "Create your frontend code simple and quickly with Bootstrap using our Drag & Drop Interface Builder."

EDIT: <strike>Almost forgot [**Easel**](https://www.easel.io/)</strike> (shutdown)

Comment: Thanks very much I think that the best we have available for now

Comment: Thanks, there are 2 interesting links on your list that I didn't know about

Comment: Easel is shutting down, actually it's already shutdown

Comment: DivShot merged with FireBase. Should we cross it out?